# Using autoload to load mockup classes when unit testing in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have a number of helper classes that are collections of static methods that used to be functions lying around in various include files. I collected them in classes to keep things tidy and effecient (by moving them out of the global namespace and loading them lazily). Normally the functions are trivial and don't depend on anything but standard PHP functions. As far as I understand, they can be tested as single units.

There are methods that use the database though. I could rewrite them, but making everything non-static for testing alone seems wrong. Injecting dependencies into every helper function also defeats the ease and neatness.

My alternative idea is a very simple testing environment where I use the PHP autoload functionality. Normally it includes the requested class from a class directory. But in the testing environment, I redirect the autoload's include to a different directory with mockup classes for testing.

Is this a good idea for testing? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can register different __autoload function using spl_autoload_register.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: True, but it's the same solution as far as the unit testing is concerned.